# Does a Chinese citizen lose citizenship if their parent applied for them to acquire foreign nationality?

Tags: immigration, citizenship, china

In Canada, a permanent resident under the age of 14 may be naturalized upon application on behalf of the minor by their custodial parent. *Citizenship Act*, s. 5(1.04)(a). This is slightly different from the situation in [1], where a minor can automatically derive United States citizenship when a parent naturalizes. For Canadian citizenship, a separate application must be made on behalf of the minor.

Does such an acquisition of Canadian citizenship qualify as a "voluntary" naturalization that results in loss of Chinese citizenship?

[1] [Is someone who was born in China but acquired citizenship elsewhere through derived citizenship still a Chinese citizen?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77691/is-someone-who-was-born-in-china-but-acquired-citizenship-elsewhere-through-deri)